# Jquery UI Droppable auto align horizontally in a container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on Jquery UI Drag & Drop, and my requirement is when I drop a div on drop container div, it will auto align to horizontally. I have tried some R&D and get a code that make it vertically align but not able to change it to horizontally.

script:

```
$(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
        $('#container').append('<div class="ui-widget-content draggable">Zone<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>');
        $(".draggable" ).draggable();

        $('.dropTarget').droppable({
            drop: function(ev, ui) {
                $(ui.draggable).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(this);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add">Add Zone</a>
<div id="container" style="height: 100px;"></div>
<div class="dropTarget" style="float: left; border:1px solid black; height: 200px; width: 200px;"></div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/36/)

Comment: Check out this Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/38/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What helped for me is adding

```
.draggable {
    float: left;
    /* rest of the css */
}
```

Hope this helps!